# Get connection string from application.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have .Infrastructure project for Entities and migrations and .Web project with `application.json` file, where I have connection string

In Infrastrusture project I have `ApplicationContextFactory` to run migrations

Here is code

```
public class ApplicationContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

This string is not working, because application,json file is in .Web project.

.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

Here is my solution structure

[image]

How I can get connection string from it?

Comment: Why not pass the connection string? It's a bit weird that the factory needs to care about the application wide configuration file and maybe later in the process figure out which environment is being started. Just pass the connection string from your Startup class.

Comment: Okay, how I can pass it to .Infrastructure project? @huysentruitw

Comment: Use Dependency injection and create an extension method and pass the connectionstring, for an example I refer to one of my projects [here](https://github.com/huysentruitw/cash-flow/blob/master/src/CashFlow.Data/Extensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

Comment: Then `AddData` is called from `Startup` class in the Host project: [see here](https://github.com/huysentruitw/cash-flow/blob/master/src/CashFlow.Host/Startup.cs#L30)

Comment: This also means dropping the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` and keeping things simple :)

Comment: Yeah, thank's @huysentruitw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run migrations for a library project but use the configured connection string from a different project, you will need to specify the startup project as you run migrations commands.

For example, to add a migration:

```
cd src\TooSeeWeb.Infrastructure
dotnet ef migrations add ExampleMigration -s ..\TooSeeWeb
```

This will specify `..\TooSeeWeb` as the startup project, so the migration will run as if everything EF related was actually inside that web project.

Similarly, that `-s` or `--startup-project` parameter can also be used with other commands, e.g. `dotnet ef database update -s ..\TooSeeWeb`.

Comment: Thank's this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is for migrating against something like a class library, where there's not a startup project involved. If you are fine with using an explicit startup project when migrating, then see @poke's answer, and get rid of your factory, as you don't need it.

However, if you want to keep going this route, you should realize that as its name indicates, this is for "design time", i.e. development. As such, getting a connection string from configuration doesn't really make sense, as it's always going to be your development database. That's why the docs just reference this connection string explicitly. Not sure why every developer seems to think they need to second-guess Microsoft on this.

It shouldn't even really pose an issue in a team environment. If you use the local `MSSQLLocalDb` instance, and all your devs are using Visual Studio, then the connection string is effectively developer agnostic. Or, if you spin up a SQL Server instance in a container, then every developer will be working off that same container setup.

If there is some scenario where you need to allow developer-specific connection strings, then you can use configuration for that. However, you should then just be hitting User Secrets, and you still don't need access to `appsettings.json` in your web project.